# Fluentd modify json output

Tags: json, fluentd

I need to modify output to from this

```
"payload": {
  "a": "value",
  "b": "value",
  .....
}
```

to

```
"a": "value",
"b": "value",
.....
```

I was looking at record_transformer but it looks like this is only to for example add new field or modify value of existing json property. Is it possible to extract data like i want to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this [If key names are fixed]

```
@type record_transformer
<record>
   a $${record["payload"]["a"]
   remove_keys payload
</record>
```

Or this plugin for dynamic keys https://github.com/kazegusuri/fluent-plugin-flatten-hash